# Save file on Downloads folder on windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I make program to download a xap file and store on local folder of application.the problem is i want to save the file on downloads folder of phone memory or SD card to install application from windows phone store app.

how can i store file on downloads folder using BackgroundDownloader
or path to downloads folder using StorageFile or URI?

how can i move file after download from local application folder to downloads folder?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the knownfolders class

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.removabledevices

This should help you.